# how to write std.error to file but std.out to console in python?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, stderr

In this example, I want to  `write` to console `(std.out)` in the `try block`; 
but when an exception is thrown by the `except block`, I want to write the exception content to `std.err` which is re-directed to a log `file`.

I could just have a `file` opened in `except` block and `write` on to it. but that needs to be done for every `try-catch` block, so if there is an alternative for `re-directing` these exceptions to `std.err` and log the std.error.

```
>>> try:
...   print "hello world"
...   1/0
... except ZeroDivisionError as e:
...   print "exception"
... 
hello world
exception
```

Comment: I didn't vote, but I can't make heads nor tails of the question (when you write something to stdout, that causes some other output to be redirected to stderr???)

Comment: @NPE: I am re-formatting the question.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: I know of this `print>> sys.stderr, 'spam'`. But I want to know if I could re-direct all sys.stderr to a file instead of it defaulting to console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is absolutely possible:

```
import sys
sys.stderr = open("/tmp/errors.txt", "w")
```

And all following prints to stderr will go to that file.

You should probably be doing this at the shell level rather than at the Python level, though -- it's far more flexible.

Comment: This has the (probably) unwanted side effect of silencing *all* Exception tracebacks by piping them into the file the asker is trying to print to.

Comment: Well OP *did* ask how to redirect all of stderr to a file. But I agree -- like I said, that's a bad idea, and something better done at the shell level.

Comment: @MaxNoel: Thanks for a solution. atleast I know this is possible, but I will not do it

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print to stderr, use `sys.stderr` and let the OS and user handle where the text printed to std.err goes. This allows a user to run `python your_script.py 2> my_err_output` on a Posix terminal and still catch the std.err content.

If you want to output logging information to a specific file, [use the logging module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) instead.

**Don't modify the behaviour of a very standard concept - that would be in err.** Proper logging allows you to catch the information you need but allows expection tracebacks (which are piped to `stderr`) to get to the user without having to find your special file.

Comment: Thanks. will follow the golden rule!

Comment: @eagertoLearn You can also follow the golden rule and mark an answer as answered to help others ;)